# $regex is reducing the performace in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, textmatching

I am trying to query a collection of 7million documents in mongodb by searching a field. I am using regex to perform partial search. It is taking lot of time to give me response. Is there any way we could improve the performance?

I have tried creating text index but $text is supporting partial search as regex

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are the main tool to speed up queries against MongoDB. However, when using `$regex` matches, indexes are only used under some special conditions. This means that the query will end up in a collection scan if you cannot add some additional filter criteria that use an index.

Hence, `$text` indexes are a much better tool for filtering text content. If this yields too many false positive results, you can use both a `$text` and a `$regex` condition to fine-tune the results, e.g.:

```
db.movies.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $text: {
        $search: "at Tiffany's",
      },
    },
    {
      title: { $regex: /at Tiffany's/ },
    },
  ],
});
```

This [blog post](https://medium.com/statuscode/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-regex-queries-by-a-factor-of-up-to-10-73995435c606) describes the procedure in greater detail.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer. But here im trying to filter it by an unknow search pharse from UI. 

For example I want to query all the documents that match for "at Tiffany's" in complete whole field like "I am at Tiffany's place". 

So will not be able to search text index filed with exact match. Is there any possibility as such.